# How to call BillingClient::queryProductDetails in Kotlin without knowing any product IDs?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-billing

I would like to use the Play Store BillingClient to get a list of all products for sale for my app and I don't want to have to hard-code my product list on the client because the IDs on the client and IDs on the Play Store can easily get out of sync. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to query products without knowing their ids. The only solution is to sync them with a remote service so they are not hardcoded on the client.